# Oracle Forms Dependency

Tags: oracle, dependency-management

Does anyone know of any tool that could give me a dependency map for an oracle 6i form?
If not a tool, then some technique I could use to analyze form dependencies such as other forms called, table or procedure used by a particular form.

Answer (score 1):

One technique that may be useful is to convert your .fmb files to text files .fmt. You find the option in Oracle Forms Builder under File -> Administration -> Convert.

The resulting .fmt file contains a lot of text that may or may not be useful to you.

An example:

```
TABLE USAGES
  BASE   NGM_DATASET                   SEL INS UPD DEL

REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY RULES
Block DATASETS
  Deletion of NGM_DATASET prevented if NGM_EXPORT_LEVERING records exist
  Foreign key(s): NGM_ELG_FILTERDST_FK
  Deletion of NGM_DATASET causes deletion of NGM_OBJECTSELECTIE
  Foreign key(s): NGM_OSE_DST_FK
  Deletion of NGM_DATASET prevented if NGM_SPATIAL_QUERY records exist
  Foreign key(s): NGM_OSE_DST_FK,NGM_SQY_OSE_FK_1
  Deletion of NGM_DATASET prevented if NGM_SPATIAL_QUERY records exist
```

Maybe it's possible to write some code that extracts the information you need from this.

Comment: Thanks Rene I will consider this... anyone else have any thing to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can check two tools:
 [ODA object dependencies analyzer](http://samtrest.com) 
The ODA has Form viewer for to look Form dependencies against Oracle database object and [ORCL Toolbox](http://www.orcl-toolbox.com/) with a forms power search.