# Code to import tables in the order of their dependencies

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus, sqldependency

I am working in a windows environment, and using Oracle SQL Developer.
I have the  whole database of an organisation that consists of some 50 csv files. Each for a table.There are two tasks that are to be performed

1. I need to import the whole data from scratch into oracle database. So I need to consider the dependencies of tables and therefore load them in that particular order. I want to automate it, as in write a script or code for it. I have the whole tree of dependencies.
   (Even though it will effectively be only performed once).
   Could you also suggest what language would be suitable for the purpose or how I should start with the job?
2. After all the upload has been done, if I get a query to update a table then all the necessary tables should be updated.

That process btw has to be done for many other organisations.

I am new to Oracle, so if you could also provide me with a good link to learn from

The closest I got to finding my answer was this -> [Oracle Forms Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708887/oracle-forms-dependency)

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not going to [recommend what language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/179419) you should use. It's expected that a question have an answer which this question does not. I'm therefore voting to close. However, there's no need to load in order. Create [primary](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php) / [foreign](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/index.php) after you've loaded the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_ldr.htm#i436326) for this task, it is designed for loading files into Oracle.  Also read about external tables since it might be possible for you to avoid the need to load them altogether.